# Why isn't border inherited from body here?

Tags: html, css

Why does'nt `#box` inherit `border` from `body` here ? I tried to inspect the html source in Chrome developer tools and noticed that `border` is not inherited.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>The Box Model</title>
<style>

body {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 10px solid black;

}

#box {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

#content {
  background-color: #90EE90; /*green*/
}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Box Model</h1>

<div id="box">
  <div id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: borders are not inherited by default.

Comment: I don't see an `inherit` anywhere in your code.. How is it supposed to inherit if you don't specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some properties are inherited by default and some are not you have to explicitly specify 'inherit' to inherit the parent properties

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

Answer (score 4):

Add this `border: inherit;` It will inherit border property from parent.

CSS:

```
#box {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  width: 300px;
  border: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the inherit property for this. You can add -

```
#box {
    border: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, "border" isn't a inherit property by default.